# How to ignore punctuation marks when comparing two files in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to extend a comparison python script to not include case items such has (lowercase/uppercase names and use of quotation marks). Currently I have the following

compare.py

```
with open('old.csv', 'r') as t1, open('new.csv', 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)
```

That correctly compares two files and outputs the difference in a third file. But say I have the following

old.csv

```
"testCaseA",
"testCaseB",
"testCaseC"
```

new.csv

```
testCaseA,
testCaseB,
```

update.csv should be

```
testCaseC
```

Comment: Just filter out capitalization and punctuation. You can use `str.lower` to filter out capitalization, and something like list comprehension to filter out punctuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `split()` and `strip()` to remove the `'\n'`,  `,` and the double `"` from the elements in the list and then a list comprehension to find the difference:

```
with open('old.txt', 'r') as t1, open('new.txt', 'r') as t2:
     fileone = [i.split(',\n', 1)[0].strip('"') for i in t1.readlines()]
     filetwo = [i.split(',\n', 1)[0].strip(',') for i in t2.readlines()]

# print(fileone)   # ['testCaseA', 'testCaseB', 'testCaseC']
# print(filetwo)   # ['testCaseA', 'testCaseB']

s = set(filetwo)
print([x for x in fileone if x not in s])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['testCaseC']
```

Comment: Thanks, for the detailed answer.
Is this also meant to work for " in the names themselves? For example removing the " in 

1/2" test case a

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using the [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) library for this.From the documentation:

> This module provides classes and functions for comparing sequences. It can be used for example, for comparing files, and can produce difference information in various formats, including HTML and context and unified diffs

[This](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#differ-example) example from the documentation is a good starting point and [this](https://pymotw.com/2/difflib/) page has a bunch of examples :)

Comment: you can improve your answer by showing a short example rater then just linking to one :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that code as following is more pretty:

```
from pathlib import Path

fn1, fn2 = 'old.csv', 'new.csv'
ss1, ss2 = [Path(fn).read_text().splitlines() for fn in (fn1, fn2)]
for ss in (ss1, ss2):
    for i, v in enumerate(ss):
        ss[i] = v.strip('\'",')

set1, set2 = [set(ss) for ss in (ss1, ss2)]

for i, line in enumerate(ss1, 1):
    if line not in set2:
        print(f'line {i}: `{line}` : in {fn1}, but not in {fn2}')

for i, line in enumerate(ss2, 1):
    if line not in set1:
        print(f'line {i}: `{line}` : in {fn2}, but not in {fn1}')
```

The last two for loop can also be:

```
for ss, line_set, f1, f2 in ((ss1, set2, fn1, fn2), (ss2, set1, fn2, fn1)):
    for i, line in enumerate(ss, 1):
        if line not in line_set:
            print(f'line {i}: `{line}` : in {f1}, but not in {f2}')
```

Comment: Thanks, for the detailed answer. Is this also meant to work for " in the names themselves? For example removing the " in 1/2" test case a